# grabbing a file from sharepoint online via CLI to on-prem (curl?)

Tags: curl, password-encryption

please bare with me, as i am not a programmer by trade.. usually just writing simple five lines in a shell script is enough to do what i need.

i am trying download a file from sharepoint online.  my company uses our userID and passwd as credentials.  How would one use a CLI command (like curl or wget) to make this request and perhaps not "cleartext" the password in the command?   I would probably need to fetch the password from active directory or some vault application.  Is this possible?

The sample command would look like this;

curl --user user:******** -o output_file "https://file_path?raw"

I have the asterisks to be pulled from a password vault as opposed to cleartext.

Comment: I am hoping some people can give any suggestion on this.   If this has been covered elsewhere, any guidance it great.